# Gradle Errors in Android Studio 0.8.2

Tags: android-studio, gradle

After creating a new project in Android Studio 0.8.2, I get a number of error messages before doing anything. At the top of the window I see "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly." At the bottom I see "Gradle 'FunFacts' project refresh failed Error:Cause: org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.getMaxStringLength()I"

I am new to all of this and I've looked on Google for solutions. However, nothing has worked yet. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I am working on a mac running OS X Yosemite v10.10.3.

Comment: I suggest you using the official version of AS 1.+

Comment: I've updated Android Studio to version 1.2.1.1 but I get the same error.